# Devise Invitable error: The invitation token provided is not valid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

Regardless of what I have tried and I have looked through this [Github thread](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/issues/402), I keep getting the error `The invitation token provided is not valid!`

I have the form embedded onto a separate page on my website and the invitation is sending, but the token seems to be wrong.

I do have this line in my mailer code

```
<p><%= link_to I18n.t("devise.mailer.invitation_instructions.accept"), accept_invitation_url(@resource, :invitation_token => @token) %></p>
```

I am also using a custom controller, but don't yet have anything in it.

Comment: hey David, did you manage to resolve this issue?